# Upload image using Javascript port

Tags: javascript, mobile, codenameone

Hi I'm trying to upload image via the Java script port. Logging seems to work and it seems the server is not receiving the "file" object. Here is my code (note this works via simulator):

```
    Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            picture = (String) evt.getSource();
            if (picture != null) {
                String url = "...";
                MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
                request.setUrl(url);
                try {
                    request.addData("file", picture, "image/png");
                    request.setFilename("file", "myPicture.png");
                    request.setPost(true);
                    request.addArgument("submit", "yes");
                    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);
                    Log.p("initVars(..)  MultipartRequest error code: " 
                                               + request.getResponseCode(), Log.DEBUG);
                    String data = new String(request.getResponseData());
                    Log.p(data, Log.DEBUG);

                } catch (IOException err) {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JavaScript deployed on the same server as the upload destination?

Assuming you are in the same server try using the build hint: `javascript.inject_proxy=false`. This will disable the proxy servlet and create direct communication to the JavaScript port.

If you are not in the same server make sure you are using the WAR distribution with the proxy servlet within so it can redirect your upload.

Comment: Add the hint: `javascript.inject_proxy=false` did not solve the problem. I kept on receiving Cross Origin issues reason being the Java Script build was hosted on the same server as the destination. Ended using **parse4cn1 .cn1lib** `ParseFile` object for uploading the images.

Comment: This might work better with a / URL or something similar to that. Did you look at the web console in the browser to see if this is the cause and what's the warning